# How to reuse scala slick "withSession { implicit session: Session =>" code block

Tags: scala, slick

I have this code in `scala` using `slick`

```
def insertTask(task: Task) = {
  conn.dbObject withSession { implicit session: Session =>
    tasks.insert(task)
  }
}
```

it looks working :)

Now I'm going to have also code for `readTask` and I do not want to duplicate the code for `withSession { implicit...`

So I thought of doing this:

```
def doWithConn(dbConn: DBConnection, doThisCodeBlock: => Unit)(implicit session: Session) = {
  dbConn.dbObject withSession { implicit session: Session =>
    doThisCodeBlock
  }
}
```

and now my code looks like

```
def insertTask(task: Task) = {
  doWithConn(conn, tasks.insert(task)) // here i get the following complication error
}
```

however I get the following compilation error:

> Error:(36, 34) could not find implicit value for parameter session: scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend#SessionDef
>           doWithConn(conn, tasks.insert(task))
>                                        ^

I'm not sure how to pass the `session` from the `insertTask` method.  How can I pass it and fix this compilation error?

thanks

Comment: In your `doWithConn` method you don't need to pass in a `Session`, you are creating it into the method body.

Comment: @EndeNeu I don't think I understand (I removed `(implicit session: Session)` I still get the same compilation error but not sure this is what you meant..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

withSession is a method that takes a function from session to whatever as an argument. The `syntax { implicit session => }` is just to make the session implicit. But you can also just pass a function:

```
val yourBlock: Session => ... = ...

db.withSession(yourBlock)
```

No need to wrap it, just use it as is :).

Chris

Comment: When I tried to define something like this: "val insertTaskInternal : Session => Unit = tasks.insert(task)" I get `Error:(32, 59) not found: value task
  val insertTaskInternal : Session => Unit = tasks.insert(task)
                                                          ^`.  (it cannot find the method insert for tasks) its working fine when its encapsulated in `conn.dbObject withSession { implicit session: Session =>`

Comment: try .insert(task)(_) to make turn the method's second argument list into a function argument. Other than that I would need to see the full code and full message.

Comment: makes sense! i'm bad at this i'm still having problems implementing the `yourBlock` I've tried it like this (in case yourBlock is drop scheme) 

`val deleteSchemeFunc: (Session => Unit) = { s: Session => tasks.ddl.drop }`

but i get compilation error:

`Error:(49, 71) could not find implicit value for parameter session: scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend#SessionDef
  val deleteSchemeFunc: (Session => Unit) = { s: Session => tasks.ddl.drop }`
                                                                      ^

Comment: ok found the answer! :)  `val deleteSchemeFunc: (Session => Unit) = { session: Session => tasks.ddl.drop(session) }`

Comment: should be identical to `val deleteSchemeFunc = tasks.ddl.drop(_)`

Comment: Also, this all is nothing Slick specific. It is pure Scala syntax and semantics questions. There maybe be some general Scala literature that explains all this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think is your `doThisCodeBlock` doesn't have a notion of a session being passed to it. I think a better way is to simply use currying for reusing statements that use the session:

```
def insertTaskStatement(task: Task)(implicit session: Session) = {
    tasks.insert(task)
}

def insertOtherThingStatement(otherThing: OtherThing)(implicit session: Session) = {
    things.insert(otherThing)
}

def insertTaskAndOtherThing(task: Task,otherThing: OtherThing) = {
  conn.dbObject withSession { implicit session: Session =>
    insertTaskStatement(task)
    insertOtherThingStatement(otherThing)
  }
}
```